# Redis node MOVED exception

Tags: vert.x, vertx-redis-client

Redis in our production environment is in cluster mode, with 6 nodes, 3 master nodes and 3 slave nodes. When nodes are switched due to network and other reasons, Redis-client cannot automatically refresh these nodes, and will report exception
 `MOVED 5649 192.168.1.1:6379`

The vertx-redis-client version I use is 4.2.1
My configuration looks like this:

```
RedisOptions options = new RedisOptions();
options.setType(RedisClientType.CLUSTER)
       .setRole(RedisRole.MASTER)
       .setUseReplicas(RedisReplicas.NEVER)
```

Every time I encounter this problem, I need to restart my application service to restore it. I want to ask if there is any way to make vertx-redis-client automatically refresh the node?
Thank you ~